# WPF non blocking UI Popup

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

In an Office Add-In I need to call a WPF which executes a function which may timeout but I want the UI to be responsive to allow the user to click the cancel/close button.
So far my code is the following:

```
// From the Ribbon
var f = new Forms.CheckConnectivityPopup();
f.doneEvent.WaitOne();

// Get the status from the popup or null if the operation was cancelled
var status = f.status;
if(status != null)

// Continue the execution
--------------------------------
public partial class CheckConnectivityPopup : MetroWindow
{
    public readonly BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    public AutoResetEvent doneEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    public Status status = null;

    public CheckConnectivityPopup()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Show();
        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }    
    private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // displayAndCheck();
        status = CheckStatus();
        Thread.Sleep(10000); // to simulate the time
    }
    private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        doneEvent.Set();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

So far the popup is frozen until sleep period is completed.

Comment: I would suggest switching over to async-await with async event handler.

Answer (score 1):

`WaitOne()` blocks the current thread. You could replace the `AutoResetEvent` with a `SemaphoreSlim`:

```
public partial class CheckConnectivityPopup : MetroWindow
{
    public readonly BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    public SemaphoreSlim doneEvent = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);
    public Status status = null;

    public CheckConnectivityPopup()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Show();
        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
    private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //displayAndCheck();
        status = CheckStatus();
        Thread.Sleep(10000); // to simulate the time
    }
    private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        doneEvent.Release();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

...that you can await asynchronously:

```
var f = new Forms.CheckConnectivityPopup();
await f.doneEvent.WaitAsync();
```

For you to be able to await the `WaitAsync()` method, you must mark the method where you create the instance of the `CheckConnectivityPopup` as `async`:

```
void async YourMethod() { ... }
```

If this is not an option for some reason, you could use the `ContinueWith` method instead:

```
var f = new Forms.CheckConnectivityPopup();
f.doneEvent.WaitAsync().ContinueWith(_ => 
{
    var status = f.status;
    if (status != null)
    {
        //...
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The await f.doneEvent.WaitAsync(); works fine but I now got an exception "The calling thread must be STA,because many UI components require this". I am trying to tag the main method with [STAThread] but I am not sure which one is the right one. I also try to use the dispatcher but I am getting other errors when doing so.